# GMOD - Weird texture glitches on Cam3D2D textured rectangle

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I get this weird textured rectangle glitch while rotating the Cam3D2D surface.

https://gyazo.com/2cf4a546d92fc71826a7ed429d9e718f

Here is the code for the textured rectangle:

```
surface.SetMaterial(m)
surface.SetDrawColor( 255, 255, 255, 255 )
surface.DrawTexturedRect( (627/2) - (512/2), 50, 512, 128 )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that the chenical formula is distorted?

Comment: it turns like black or glitches

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.vmt` file and if at the first line is written `LightmappedGeneric` just change it to `UnlitGeneric`.